# Unable to attach files using ant <files>

Tags: email, ant, jakarta-mail

I am not getting the attachment in the email with the above command but it prints something in the bodymessage.

```
<mail mailhost="@{smtp-host}" messagemimetype="text/html" subject="@{message-subject}" tolist="${mail_recipients}" cclist="${cc_recipients}" files="e:\test.txt" from="@{from-address}" charset="utf-8" messagefile="@{message-file}">
```

Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: I am using the below command.<mail mailhost="@{smtp-host}" messagemimetype="text/html" subject="@{message-subject}" tolist="${mail_recipients}" cclist="${cc_recipients}" files="e:\test.txt" from="@{from-address}" charset="utf-8" messagefile="@{message-file}">

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't see a way to enable [JavaMail debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) using the ant task.

Try using sub-elements instead of attributes, as in the examples on the [ant mail task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mail.html) page.